# What is the identity of this spider from India?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image: Photo taken at Tamilnadu, India]

I came across this strange guy today at my classroom in Tamil Nadu, India. It is a spider which is not very much bigger than an ant but with an artistic body. He has 8 legs, but the two on the front are raised above his head, just like a crab does. Can anyone identify this little guy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyone identify this little guy?

That is a *[Siler semiglaucus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siler_semiglaucus)*, which is a type of [jumping spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider). It has the nickname of "metallic jumper", and can be found all throughout India, Indonesia, Philippines, and Thailand.

[image]

[image]

> He has 8 legs, but the two on the front is raised above his head, just like a crab does.

[image]

[Here](https://www.projectnoah.org/organisms?search=Siler+semiglaucus) is a wonderful collection of more images, which also includes locations of discovery.